# JavaScript need to avoid global variable

Tags: javascript, html

currently I am a beginner in JavaScript. I would like to make my website can change a picture everytime I click a button.

This is my HTML file:

```
<div id="images">
    <img src="img/80673284_74c3361ed19c018192c338d338d27d67.jpg" id="previewimage">
</div>
<button onclick="changepic()" id="buttonback" class="btn btn-primary">Back</button>
```

After I click the button, the `changepic` function will be executed. And this is my Javascript code :

```
function changepic(source){
    document.getElementById('previewimage').src = source;
}
```

And I take the "source" parameter as a string variable which is a link.
My plan is to call this function for every elements in my array which I called "link". But Isn't that mean I need to make my variable `link=[]` as a global variable? I thought, doing javascript, we need to avoid global variable as much as possible. To create the link every time I press the button will not be possible since it is not efficient.

Any idea?

Comment: I will store that array in php and return as json to javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"I thought, doing javascript, we need to avoid global variable as much as possible"* - It's true that global variables are to be used only when necessary, but you should not avoid them altogether.

In your case, the alternative for not using a global variable is passing an argument to the function, with the current image name, or index, or querying the current image used using the element's attributes, which would make the code a bit more messy and over complicated, so there's nothing wrong with using a global parameter with your code.

As you suggested, create a `links` array and increment its index on every click.

Here's an example.

```js
var currentImage = 0;
var links = [
     "http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg",
     "http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/2.jpg",
     "http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/3.jpg"
];
    
function changepic() {

    // Increment the value
    currentImage++;
    
    // Reset the counter if all images were used
    if (currentImage >= links.length)
        currentImage = 0;
    
    document.getElementById('previewimage').src = links[currentImage];
}
```

```html
<div id="images">
    <img src="http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/4.jpg" id="previewimage" width="200">
</div>
<button onclick="changepic();" id="buttonback" class="btn btn-primary">Back</button>
```

Comment: "what you are trying to achieve does require declaring a global variable" What?? This couldn't be farther from the truth. What are you trying to do to the poor guy? It is not a matter of opinion, but a matter of fact that this is false. I'm not gonna downvote because I'm forgiving, but please remove this atrocity from Stack Overflow.

Comment: @bowheart If you have a better answer go ahead and post it.

Comment: I'm not saying you're answer is bad, mon. The rest of it is fine. Hence no downvote. I'm just asking you to remove the line about global variables being required. I just feel awful letting a beginner get that notion. That's all. :)

Comment: Why thank you. I might also add that if you bind the click handler from JavaScript, rather than in the HTML, and wrap the JavaScript in an IIFE, all global variables will be gone. But hey, thanks for being a sport.

Comment: @bowheart There are a thousand ways to do what the OP requested, As the OP is a starter,  I just posted the simplest way making sure he does not avoid using global variables altogehter. Thank you to for being a sport.

Comment: Thank you for your help guys @bowheart &Koby, I learned something today ! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about this ! It can avoid your link from global variable ....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function link() {
  return [
  "link1",
  "link2",
  "link3"
  ];
}
function changepic(){
    var lk = link();
    //implement code
    //document.getElementById('previewimage').src = source;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for your solution but, I got like 2000 pictures which I cannot write it one by one. I am reading it from CSV files, the name of each image. Thanks btw!